# Ultraviolet | Generating a proxied URL version when a client accesses the Ultraviolet App express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

[Ultraviolet App](https://github.com/titaniumnetwork-dev/Ultraviolet-App) is a library based on [Ultraviolet](https://github.com/titaniumnetwork-dev/Ultraviolet), used to bypass blockages of various services. I am trying to use it to implement my task:

There is a list of services, and the idea is that by clicking on one of them, a request should be sent to the `Ultraviolet App`, which should return a proxied version of that service's URL for subsequent embedding in an iframe's src attribute, providing access to the service.

The code of the proxy server in `express` in `index.js`, with some of my modifications (I added a route handler `/generate-proxy-url` and am trying to import `Ultraviolet`), currently looks like this:

```
import { createBareServer } from "@tomphttp/bare-server-node";
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "node:http";
import { publicPath } from "ultraviolet-static";
import { uvPath } from "@titaniumnetwork-dev/ultraviolet";
import { join } from "node:path";
import { hostname } from "node:os";
import Ultraviolet from '@titaniumnetwork-dev/ultraviolet';

const bare = createBareServer("/bare/");
const app = express();

/* added */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Разрешить все домены
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

/* added */
app.get('/generate-proxy-url', (req, res) => {
  const serviceUrl = req.query.url;

  if (serviceUrl) {
    const encodedUrl = Ultraviolet.encodeUrl(serviceUrl);
    const proxyUrl = `http://localhost:${port}/service/${encodedUrl}`;
    res.send(proxyUrl);
  } else {
    res.status(400).send('No URL provided');
  }
});

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use("/uv/", express.static(uvPath));

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404);
  res.sendFile(join(publicPath, "404.html"));
});

const server = createServer();

server.on("request", (req, res) => {
  if (bare.shouldRoute(req)) {
    bare.routeRequest(req, res);
  } else {
    app(req, res);
  }
});

server.on("upgrade", (req, socket, head) => {
  if (bare.shouldRoute(req)) {
    bare.routeUpgrade(req, socket, head);
  } else {
    socket.end();
  }
});

let port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || "");

if (isNaN(port)) port = 8080;

server.on("listening", () => {
  const address = server.address();
});

process.on("SIGINT", shutdown);
process.on("SIGTERM", shutdown);

function shutdown() {
  server.close();
  bare.close();
  process.exit(0);
}

server.listen({
  port,
});
```

The problem is that `Ultraviolet` doesn't import, so the encoding of the original service URL into its proxied version `const encodedUrl = Ultraviolet.encodeUrl(serviceUrl);` doesn't work. No matter how I try to import it, nothing works. Yes, there is very little documentation for these libraries.

In the current version - when accessing the proxy server, the error is that `Ultraviolet.encodeUrl is not a function`. If using `const encodedUrl = Ultraviolet.codec.xor.encode(serviceUrl);` the error is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'xor')`.

In short, I can't `encode` the URL, and I have no idea how to solve the problem.

P.S. I would add the `Ultraviolet` tag here, but I don't have enough rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the code Ultraviolet uses to encode the url, it's currently this:

```
function encode(str) {
    if (!str) return str;
    return encodeURIComponent(
        str
            .toString()
            .split('')
            .map((char, ind) =>
                ind % 2 ? String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() ^ 2) : char
            )
            .join('')
    );
}
```